# Fading in HTML text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to get some text to fade in from opacity 0 to 100, but I can't seem to get it to work right. Credits to the person for the original fadeOut version.

Here's the code...

```
fadeIn = function(id, speed) {
    var s = document.getElementById(id).style;
    s.opacity = 0;
    (function fade() {(s.opacity+= .1)<100?s.display="inline":setTimeout(fade,speed)})();
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use `jQuery` in your task or somewhat?

Comment: I kinda want to avoid using a external library, but I'm aware that it'll make this so much easier. I would like a solution in vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Yes. It would be `$('#" + id).fadeOut(2000)` where 2000 is 2 seconds :) Just in case you will use it.

Comment: I'll be sure to use this when I play around with JQuery more in the future. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are 2 problems, 1 the opacity values vary from `0...1` not `0..100` also when opacity is 1 you need to stop the loop.

Second, `s.opacity` returns a string, so since you are using `+` operator you need to convert the value to a string else a string concatenation will be performed

```js
fadeIn = function(id, speed) {
  var s = document.getElementById(id).style;
  s.opacity = 0;
  (function fade() {
    (s.opacity = +s.opacity + .1) >= 1 ? s.display = "inline" : setTimeout(fade, speed)
  })();
}

fadeIn('s', 500)
```

```html
<div id="s">asdfsadf</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is set an interval and then count up to 100 by your speed/100 in increments.

```js
function fadeIn(id, speed) {
  var max = 100, count = 0;
  var increment = speed / max;       
    
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    obj.style.opacity = (count / max);
    if (count == max) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    count++;
  }, increment);
}
```

```css
#faded {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="faded">Fade me in</div>
<button onclick="fadeIn('faded', 3000)">Fade it in</button>
```